# how to get the mouse position on a QPixmap and not on the QMainWindow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

[image]I

I have one QMainWindow which contains a QWidget with a QPixmap in that. When I try to get the location of mouse click, it shows based on the QMainWindow and not based on the QPixmap (even on the gray area out of the image). Can anyone help me how can I transfer the x,y position from QMainWindow to QPixmap (Image) coordinates only?

The following code returns the x,y coordinates of the whole QMainWindow and not the QPixmap (only on the image) specifically.

```
 class ImageViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self, input, name):
            super(ImageViewer, self).__init__()
            self.image_series = input
            self.starter()


      def starter(self): 
           self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
           self.main_Viewer_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
           self.setCentralWidget(self.main_Viewer_frame)
           self.main_Viewer_frame_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
           self.show()
           self.main_Viewer_frame.mousePressEvent = self.getpos

     def getpos(self, event):
           x = event.pos().x()
           y = event.pos().y()
           print(x,y)


class SliceViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

     def __init__(self, input, *args, **kwargs):
          self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
          super(SliceViewer, self).__init__(self.scene, *args, **kwargs)
          self.setScene(self.scene)
          self.img_overlay = self.scene.addPixmap(self.getPixmap(input))


viewer = SliceViewer(img.png)
window = ImageViewer(img.png, "Super Mario")
window.layout.addwidget(viewer)
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Your code does not reproduce what you show, in conclusion it is not an MRE

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors:

- Do not assign a function to a method that inherits from the class as mousePressEvent because it already has a predefined behavior but when you do X you are deleting it.
- You have to use the mouseClicked method of the QGraphicsView to get the click on the scene, and then make the necessary conversions to obtain the position with respect to the QGraphicsPixmapItem (which is equivalent to a position with respect to the QPixmap).

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class SliceViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    pixmapClicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):
        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        super(SliceViewer, self).__init__(self._scene, *args, **kwargs)
        self.img_overlay = self._scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        vp = event.pos()
        if self.itemAt(vp) == self.img_overlay:
            sp = self.mapToScene(vp)
            lp = self.img_overlay.mapFromScene(sp).toPoint()
            self.pixmapClicked.emit(lp)
        super(SliceViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class ImageViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)

        viewer = SliceViewer("/path/of/Super Mario")

        central_widget = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtGui.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(viewer)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 512, 512)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_pixmapClicked(self, point):
        print(point)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ImageViewer()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```